# Why is httpclientandroidlib in my android apk as a dependency?

Tags: java, android, android-build, androidhttpclient

When I analyse an app apk with method count analysis tools like [apk method count](http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/) I've found that ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib is always there as a dependency in the app. (with 3000+ methods)

When I try to analyse dependencies using

```bash
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

'ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib' does not show up as a dependency in any way.

I understand that 'ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib' is a [repackaging of HttpClient 4.3.1 for Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/httpclientandroidlib/) but I have no idea why its there, any suggestions on why it shows up?

I am compiling against api level 23 and our min api level is 14.

Edit: adding the current dependencies:

```bash
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1
    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
    +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1
    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1
    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13
    +--- com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.0
    |    +--- com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp-common:2.0.0
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1 -> 23.1.1
    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 23.1.1 (*)
    +--- com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:viewstate:2.0.0
    |    \--- com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.0 (*)
    +--- de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0-beta1
    +--- com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0
    +--- com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0
    +--- com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.7
    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0 -> 23.1.1
    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.4
    +--- de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.7.0
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
    +--- org.solovyev.android:checkout:0.6.0
    +--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 -> 23.1.1 (*)
    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1 -> 23.1.1 (*)
    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1 -> 23.1.1
    +--- se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
    +--- com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6
    +--- com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.7
    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.2
    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
    +--- com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.0
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
    +--- project :lib-mylib
    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0 (*)
    +--- project :lib-mylib
    \--- project :lib-mylib
         \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
```

Comment: Please post your dependencies report. We cannot suggest which third-party library contains `ch.boye.*` classes without knowing what third-party libraries you are using.

Comment: hey @CommonsWare have added the list of dependencies

Comment: Yeesh. That's a long list. Any of them could conceivably have those classes baked in, though we can rule out the ones from Google and Square. There may be an easy way to find out which does, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Sure, thanks anyway @CommonsWare